# Finding records where values of multiple columns are equal to another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

The important parts of my table are a member's unique identifier, a date, a main item type identifier, and any of three alternative item type identifiers.

What I'm trying to do is find records where any of the alternative item type identifiers ended up in the main item type identifier column at a later date for the same person. Here's an example table:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|NAME|DATE   |MAIN ITEM|ALT ITEM 1|ALT ITEM 2|ALT ITEM 3|
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|John|9/11/12|  12345  |  99999   |  88888   |  77777   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
|John|9/12/12|  99999  |  66666   |  55555   |  44444   |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to find records like the second one here that is a later date than the other for this person and was previously an alternate item to this particular person. The table I'm in has about 1700 records and about 300 of them are multiples of a person.

If the solution can't be done through Access SQL, I'm fine with VBA. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT u1.NAME, u1.Date, u1.[MAIN ITEM], u2.NAME, u2.Date, u2.ITEM
FROM (
    SELECT Test.NAME, Test.DATE, Test.[MAIN ITEM]
    FROM Test)  AS u1 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Test.NAME, Test.DATE, Test.[ALT ITEM 1]  As Item
    FROM Test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Test.NAME, Test.DATE, Test.[ALT ITEM 2] As Item
    FROM Test
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Test.NAME, Test.DATE, Test.[ALT ITEM 3] As Item
    FROM Test)  AS u2 
ON (u1.NAME = u2.NAME) AND (u1.[MAIN ITEM] = u2.[ITEM])
WHERE u1.Date>u2.date
```

I have called the table test.